# How do I stop fprintf from printing \r's to file along with \n in Windows

Tags: c, windows, printf, line-endings

When I use fprintf:

```
fprintf(somefile,"%c",'\n');
```

It prints '\r\n' to the file. How do I just print '\n'?
I'm writing to a binary file. The code above is just for debugging.

Comment: fopen("<yourfile>", "wb")

Comment: Why do you want to stop it? `"\r\n"` is how Windows indicates the end of a line in a text file. If you write just the `"\n"`, you'll get an invalid text file that other Windows programs might not handle correctly.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That might have been true a decade ago. Nowadays stuff handles proper text files just fine. :-) Note that cygwin (unless you botch the global config, which will break lots of programs) always uses binary mode, and stdio treating text and binary identically is required for POSIX conformance.

Comment: @r if most modern text editors and/or other program under Windows do handle \n-only textfiles correctly, Windows still Notepad doesn't.

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying you shouldn't do this. You might have a perfectly good reason for omitting the `'\r'` characters (and thus creating strictly invalid Windows text files). But if so, knowing what that reason is could make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm writing to a binary file

Comment: Ok, that's a good reason. Can you update your question to make that clear? (I also wonder why you'd write a newline to a binary file; is it a format that assigns a particular meaning to bytes with the value of LF?)

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, an executable file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open the file you have to open it in binary mode and not in text mode.
This is done like this:

```
fopen("filename", "wb");
```